# Use without installing

Tags: release-juno, live-installation, live-cd

I have my pc dual booted(win10 & ubuntu) and I'd like to try Elementary OS. Can i somehow try it for one time without installing it(and obviously not removing anything from my current OSs) and then IF i like it proceed with installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can... just [create an install drive](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium), boot from it and choose where it says "Try elementary OS without installing" in the boot menu

And later, inside if you want to install it just execute where it says something like "Install elementaryOS"

---

Fragment of `grub.conf` from `elementaryos-5.0-stable.20181016.iso`

```
menuentry "Try elementary OS without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install elementary OS" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Comment: Oh great. This can't fail, right? It won't delete any of my existing partitions!?

Comment: Yes, it's running off your USB media. This is the same for every other Linux distro.